# How to use AWS (lambda or api gateway) to proxy an authorized download request?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a web app that connects to AWS Cognito for authentication.  In turn, the app uses a lambda function to connect to an external API.  The app collects information  from that API and stores it in a dynamodb table, for use with Cognito authorized users.  At no point in time does the end-user have access to the token that connects them to the external API.  This is important because the end-user could use that token in a malicious way and get me in trouble with the API provider.  Essentially, my app acts as a buffer and an aggregator between the end-user and the external API.

The external API provides file urls for direct download, that require authorization.  I would like to make these available to the end-user.  As I stated, I don't want to give them direct authorization, but somehow instead proxy that request through lambda and then redirect it to the end-user.  This is where I'm stuck.

Clearly I could download the file using lambda and S3, and then in turn make it available to the end-user.  This is not a good solution because it requires quite a bit of resources to download, store and then upload the file to the end-user.  Also, there would be a gap between the time the user wanted the file and the time when it was downloaded to S3 and ready to upload to the user.

[NodeJS stream out of AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149186/nodejs-stream-out-of-aws-lambda-function/53151808#53151808) indicates that lambda functions don't support Node streams as responses, so that idea of somehow starting a download in lambda and then passing the stream along doesn't seem feasible.  I'm not sure that makes any sense anyway.

I don't know if it is possible for lambda (or api gateway) to return a redirect somehow, with the authorization embedded in such a way that the end-user doesn't have access to the token.  I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, but it seems like a reasonable use case to me.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.